# Find location of tower using google geolocation api

Tags: javascript, json, rest, geolocation, google-api

I am trying to find the location of cell towers using MNC, MCC, lac and CellID.

I have tried many api's such as opencell, combian etc. But none of them are free.

Is there any rest free API available, but for the moment I am using Google geolocation api.
  I am sending request in javascript like this

```
https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=xxx&homeMobileNetworkCode=410&homeMobileCountryCode=310&locationAreaCode=415&cellId=42&format=json
```

and all the time it return "Not Found"

I checked many places on stackover, but could not find good solution or hint. In addition is there any Free Api Available for getting operator name by using data mnc, mcc, cellid and lac.

In addition, I have also tried to use this [link](http://android-coding.blogspot.fr/2011/06/convert-celllocation-to-real-location.html) to get location but I could not as I can not find what parameter I need to pass and what should be the url I need to create.

Please provide me some guidelines to get location and operator name for specific tower by using information such as mnc, mcc etc.

Thanks appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Google describes the `geolocate` API endpoint [in their docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/). You tried to do a `GET` request, but they say that you should use `POST`, with JSON-Formatted data:

> Communication is done over HTTPS using POST. Both request and response are formatted as JSON, and the content type of both is application/json.

If you want to use the undocumented API from your link, the URL is http://www.google.com/glm/mmap and the `POST`-data is what is written in the function `WriteData`. See [the Java Docs for `DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#method_summary) if you are unfamiliar with the output produced by the various `write..`-methods.

As for getting the operator name, [there are free databases available for that](http://mcclist.com/mobile-network-codes-country-codes.asp) ([alternative 1](http://www.opencelldb.net/), [alternative 2](http://www.imei.info/operator-codes/); search google for more, there are plenty).

Comment: Hi Thanks for info, but there is not api available for getting operator from any of these links

Comment: Its static data that seldom changes, so there's no need for an API. Simply download the list and do an offline lookup in your application.